# how to install Open Source Samba tool 'smbget' on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, smb

It seems [smbget](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbget.1.html) is not available on Homebrew. Also the Samba suite not available.

> This tool is part of the samba(7) suite.
>
> smbget is a simple utility with wget-like semantics, that can download
>   files from SMB servers. You can specify the files you would like to
>   download on the command-line.
>
> The files should be in the smb-URL standard, e.g. use
>   smb://host/share/file for the UNC path \\HOST\SHARE\file.

What's the easiest way to install `smbget` on macOS?

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 with homebrew it's as easy as

```
brew install samba
```